# Two plugins. Both have click events on the same element but one of them cancels out the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

(Question below)

Here the first script which acts as a filter that when **.filter buttons a** is clicked all divs associated to the corresponding data-filter name are filtered out. So basically I have one click function there.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    var t = $(".filter-container");
    t.imagesLoaded(function() {
        t.isotope({
            itemSelector: "figure",
            filter: "*",
            resizable: false,
            animationEngine: "jquery"
        })
    });
    $(".filter-buttons a").click(function() {
        var n = $(this).parents(".filter-buttons");
        n.find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        var r = $(this).attr("data-filter");
        t.isotope({
            filter: r
        });
        event.preventDefault()
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var n = $(window).width();
        t.isotope("reLayout")
    }).trigger("resize")
});
```

Here the 2nd script which works for my **.filter-buttons ul li a** drop down list. There is also a click event acting on the same element.

```
   function DropDown(el) {
            this.f = el;
            this.placeholder = this.f.children('span');
            this.opts = this.f.find('ul.dropdown > li');
            this.val = '';
            this.index = -1;
            this.initEvents();
        }
        DropDown.prototype = {
            initEvents : function() {
                var obj = this;

                obj.f.on('click', function(event){
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    event.preventDefault()
                });

                obj.opts.on('click',function(){
                    var opt = $(this);
                    obj.val = opt.text();
                    obj.index = opt.index();
                    obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
                });
            },
            getValue : function() {
                return this.val;
            },
            getIndex : function() {
                return this.index;
            }
        }

        $(function() {

            var f = new DropDown( $('#f') );

            $(document).click(function() {
                // all dropdowns
                $('.filter-buttons').removeClass('active');
            });

        });
```

My question is how exactly do I prevent the first script canceling the second out out and vice-versa?
I tried removing the "return false" line and also tried changing the order of the script but non of it solved the issue. I thought of merging them but to be honest im not sure how this is done or if it is the correct way.

```
  <div id="f" class="filter-buttons" tabindex="1">
                        <span>Choose Genre</span>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">All</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".electronic">Electronic</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".popular">Popular</a></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Does the first **filter buttons** have a dash?

Comment: try using `event.preventDefault()` instead of returning `false`

Comment: @Winestone yes it does. That is the class name

Comment: @charlietfl that does not work either. I might have to use pure css for those click events

Comment: Could you wrap the element in a throwaway element (or make a new child inside your element) and assign one of the handlers to the parent/child?

Comment: @JaredSmith added the code in my question. You can see my elements there. right now I am not sure how this can be done. I dont think I can use any child inside my li

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong with your jQuery, I tried a slightly stripped down version of your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".filter-buttons a").click(function() {
        alert("click 1");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

function DropDown(el) {
    this.f = el;
    this.placeholder = this.f.children('span');
    this.opts = this.f.find('ul.dropdown > li');
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;
        
        obj.f.on('click', function(event){
            alert("click 2");
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            event.preventDefault()
        });
        
        obj.opts.on('click',function(){
            var opt = $(this);
            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
        });
    },
    getValue : function() {
        return this.val;
    },
    getIndex : function() {
        return this.index;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    console.log($("#f"), $("#f").on);
    var f = new DropDown( $('#f') );
    
    $(document).click(function() {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.filter-buttons').removeClass('active');
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="f" class="filter-buttons" tabindex="1">
    <span>Choose Genre</span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".electronic">Electronic</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".popular">Popular</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It seems to work, (press Run code snippet). But when I ran that on jsfiddle, with jQuery v1.6.4, it did not work, as for some reason `$("#f")` did not contain the `on` function, so `obj.f.on('click', function(event){` would not assign an event, but instead produce an error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` (for me on Chrome). I tried replacing the `.on('click',` with `.click(` and that seemed to work. So this may mean you need a more recent version of jQuery (v1.7 or above) as looking at jQuery's `.on()` documentation (http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

or use `.click()` instead.